# How long can US citizens stay in Panama?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, panama, visa-expiration

I am a U.S. passport holder, I arrived in Panama on April 12th. How long can I legally stay and how long do I have to leave before I can come back in the country legally?

Answer (score 4):

As of 2022 you have to **leave Panama for a minimum of 30 days** before coming back and getting a new 180 day allowance - assuming the immigration officer is not having a bad day:) or they think you are trying to live in Panama on a tourist visa.

Answer (score 2):

You can stay for exactly **180 days**, inclusive of the day of arrival. This means you need to leave by 23:59 on October 8th, 2016. In theory, you can leave and immediately come back, but you'd have to prove you're not trying to live in Panama on a tourist visa.

Source: [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=PA&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=00&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C).